# JSP convert string to object

Tags: jsp

As the title said, I want to execute following code

```
<%
  String res = "response.sendError ( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,\"You don't have enough privileges\" );";
%>
<%=res%>
```

so when I execute this code I need to get `http 401 Unauthorized error`.

Since it is in string format I get following string in browser instead of get `http 401 Unauthorized error`

> response.sendError ( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"You don't have enough privileges" );

So how can I convert this string into object so that I can get `http 401 Unauthorized error`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<% response.sendError(...); %>
```

The `<% ... %>` delimiters already execute code directly.

Comment: I get `response.sendError(...)` from another application to .jsp file, So the another application is the one decide whether or not send `response.sendError(...)`. The application is send this `response.sendError(...)` in string format, so I need to convert it from string to object.

Comment: @niren That's a silly design. Java doesn't really have a way to evaluate strings. Have this application send you some simple indicator that you should error out (e.g. a string with the value `"error"`), and use something like `<% if (res.equals("error")) { response.sendError(...); } %>`. (That said this isn't how I'd actually do it, but I don't know what the interface between this other application and your web application is and why it involves generating JSP.)